# Convert string of tuples to list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I am reading a CSV file with Pandas and encountering a parsing problem wherein single quotes are dropped, thereby changing string values into undefined variables as seen by Python.
NOTE: I have not found a "convert string to list" topic here that applies to my problem.

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
template_name,detect_time,no_chans,detect_val,detect_ratio,chans
2019_04_27t01_41_43,2018-05-04T12:18:09.633400Z,2,1.33368,0.666838109493,"('CHI', 'BHZ'), ('S14K', 'BHZ')"
2018_09_02t00_56_23,2018-05-10T16:40:33.508400Z,2,-1.34189,-0.670946359634,"('FALS', 'BHZ'), ('SDPT', 'BHZ')"
```

The last column, named chans should be read as a list of tuples. I am reading the file with Pandas.
I've converted the column using either `pd.eval` or `ast.literal_eval`. Both of these strip the inner single quotes, so I end up with a variable name instead of a string.

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfile, converters={'chans':ast.literal_eval})
df['chans']
0                               ((CHI, BHZ), (S14K, BHZ))
1                              ((FALS, BHZ), (SDPT, BHZ))
```

Using pd.eval the result is virtually the same, but it converts to a list of lists:

```
0                               [[CHI, BHZ], [S14K, BHZ]]
1                              [[FALS, BHZ], [SDPT, BHZ]]
```

The single quotes around the strings have been dropped and now Python interprets `(CHI, BHZ)` as a tuple of two undefined variables.

If I don't use any converter `pd.read_csv(dfile)`, I get strings like this:

```
0                         ('CHI', 'BHZ'), ('S14K', 'BHZ')
1                        ('FALS', 'BHZ'), ('SDPT', 'BHZ')
```

I guess I could process this to get what I want - a list of those tuples for each row - but are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Have you considered iterating over the list directly instead of through Pandas?

Comment: Iterating over the list won't work, because the individual elements of the list appear as a variable, e.g., CHI, and not as a string 'CHI'. So any operation throws an error.

Comment: I  misspoke, I meant the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda using `list(eval)` as your converter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfile, converters={'chans':lambda x:list(eval(x))})
```

this will give you a list of tuples instead of just a string.

Comment: @jjramsey You are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution: the much maligned Python function `eval`. I had ignored this possibility due to so many warnings: slow speed and insecure. But security is not an issue for me, and `eval` can do the job.
However `eval` only works correctly from Python and not within Pandas. So my code gets a bit ugly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfile)
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row['chans'] = eval(row['chans'])
```

These other "solutions" don't do the job, because they strip the single quotes:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfile)
df['chans'] = df['chans'].apply(eval)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dfile, converters={'chans':eval})
```

It's a pity that I have to use `iterrows`.

I'd be curious to hear of other solutions. Since I don't care if the string gets interpreted as tuples or lists, involving json seemed to be a possibility.